# Administration with Cake 3 - Prefix

Tags: cakephp-3.0

i'm actually at test CakePHP3, and i don't know how do a administration, with Cake 2, in Core we can write

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

But with CakePHP3, we don't have Core, and in documentation i don't find this code ! I try the routing

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) { 
  //My route   
  $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
```

but without success !

Comment: "_Doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description. Besides, this is documented in detail in the Cookbook: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing**

Comment: In your controller, use: namespace App\Controller\Admin;

Comment: Hey there, please mark the highest voted answer as correct answer. It worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

Three Steps:

- In `config/routes.php`: add the following to the end of the file:

  ```
  Router::prefix('Admin', function ($routes) {
      $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
  });
  ```
- Create `src/Controller/Admin` and move your `UsersController.php` file (which you would have otherwise created in the upper-level `Controller`) into it. Add the following line right after the `<?php` opening tag

  ```
  namespace App\Controller\Admin;
  ```
- Create the views.
  Create a `Template/Users/Admin` folder and dump all the add.ctp, edit.ctp, view.ctp files into it.

The Admin prefix will be used to refer to the admin section. Replace `Admin` if you want a different prefix.

I just found this is the best way of doing it at the moment. If anyone has better way then please share it.

Answer (score 2):

In cakephp 3.x change routing concept,
`Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));`
If u want to use it,
Please make a admin folder inside ur controller folder and write a same name controller name in this folder. 
If u want to `admin_index()` function like 2.x then u write only `index()` function in admin folder controller .

Note one things, in your `router.php` add this code

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) { 
  //My route   
  $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain with the help of examples, this is a good example. But i am not able to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solutions for admin prefix. Please have a look on the following code:

in **app/config/routes.php**

```
Router::prefix('admin', function($routes) {
$routes->connect('/', ['controller'=>'Users','action'=>'login']);
$routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
```

Make Admin folder inside Controller
src: **src/Controller/Admin/UsersController.php**

add this line of code in UsersController.php

```
namespace App\Controller\Wcbadmin;
```

Now make the view file: 
**src/Template/Admin/Users/login.ctp**

Answer (score 1):

Hey not sure if anyone ever got you the answer you needed. I was also having an issue getting prefix routing to work. I found that all of these solutions, even the CakePHP 3.X cookbook left out some details. Below is exactly what I did. I am using version 3.1.3.

In my **routes.php** file I added

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
     // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
     // And have the prefix => admin route element added.
     $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Index', 'action' => 'index']);    
     $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

This is from the [cookbook on prefix routing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing). All I changed was changing the controller from "Pages" to "Index".

I then created a controller located at **src/Controller/Admin/IndexController.php**

The contents of my controller were originally this (beware this part was incorrect, I correct it afterwards)

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller; // INCORRECT NAMESPACE

// INCORRECTLY MISSING use Cake\Controller\AppController
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class IndexController extends AppController{

    public function index(){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Admin Dashboard');
    } // END INDEX ACTION


}
```

After receiving an error message saying "Class IndexController not found" I then had to change the file to the following. I found this out by reading the entire error message. This was the information that I did not see in the cookbook or any of the answers you have received.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin; // THIS IS THE CORRECT NAME SPACE

use App\Controller\AppController; // HAVE TO USE App\Controller\AppController
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class IndexController extends AppController{

    public function index(){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Admin Dashboard');
    } // END INDEX ACTION


}
```

Comment: Thank you! This comment saved me from making a separate app controller for each of my prefixes!